# Is it acceptable to place view logic in a strongly typed view-data class?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, uiviewcontroller, viewdata

Say you've got a view which requires some piece of data which requires some calculation, but no outside dependances. (For example, an enumerable string listing of the past 5 years.) Is it acceptable to place this in a strongly typed view class?

Something like this:

```
class HomeIndexViewData
{

// ...some view data...

public IEnumerable<String> LastThreeYears
        {
            get
            {
                return new string[] { 
                    DateTime.Now.Year.ToString(), 
                    (DateTime.Now.Year - 1).ToString(), 
                    (DateTime.Now.Year - 2).ToString() };
            }
        }
}
```

Now, what if that calculation is dependant on some other property in the view data class? Suppose that if the year appears in a list of dates this 'LastThreeYears' property appends an asterisk to the end of the year?

Disclaimers: This is only for data that is specific to a single view and wouldn't be properly handled by a repository, view model, etc.

On one hand it seems to me that the view data should be just that: a lifeless collection of properties which are simply passed to the view from the controller. On the other hand, this is so much prettier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would do this. I think that property is OK. If you think of it as a VIEW MODEL, then it has VIEW LOGIC that way, doesn't it? It is definitely better than a lump of spaghetti code intertwined with the markup (I don't like these, though sometimes there's no running).

The property is read only, it is used to output a result which is specifically needed by the view. My vote is - yes, go for it.

Comment: I'm leaning this way as well for that reason...I'm a little murky on the MVC/MVVM/ViewData aspects, but my more general programming instincts tell me to favor readablity.

Comment: +1, if the logic is view specific e.g. decide whether or not display some data then logic belongs in viewdata.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a quite bad code. Because of view data is the data model for single view page. So, you shouldn't write some logic in here. It should be written in controller class.

By the way, if this view data is called from a lot of view pages, I suggest you to move initializing source code to constructor of view data class.

**Update**

Please use the following pattern. Don't calculate value when it is called. Because it may affects your performance. Moreover, it much likes method pattern more than get-only property.

```
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        // Initial value of all fields and property
    }

    public IEumerable<string> SomeProperty { get; protected/private set; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried to head this off with the disclaimer...this class is a typed *view data* object in ADDITION to the shared *view model*.

Comment: Yes, calculate the data only once, but it seems still there is some confusion between (what I'm calling) the view model (representing an abstraction of the domain model) vs typed view data (the data passed from the controller to a particular view), akin to using ViewData["field"]. In my solution I have an existing view model, and I'm creating a data class for each view, most/all of which include view model objects.